# Solving $\int_0^4 \frac{\left(y^2-4 y+5\right) \sin (y-2)}{2 y^2-8 y+11} d y$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^4 \frac{\left(y^2-4 y+5\right) \sin (y-2)}{2 y^2-8 y+11} d y$$
Here is my attempt
$$
\begin{aligned}
& y-2=t \Rightarrow d y=d t \\
& y^2-4 y+4=t^2 \Rightarrow 2 t^2=2 y^2-8 y+8 \\
& {y^2-4 y+5=t^2+1} \\
& 2 y^2-8 y+11=2 t^2+3 \\
& 2 y^2-8 y+10+1=2 t^3+3 \\
& 2\left(y^2-4 y+5\right)+1=2 t^3+3 . \\
& {\int_0^4 \frac{2\left(t^2+1\right) \sin t}{2\left(t^2+1\right)+1} d t} \\
& \Rightarrow \int_0^4\frac{\sin t}{\left.1+\frac{1}{2\left(t^2+1\right)}\right)} d t
\end{aligned}
$$

No other substitution seems to work. Any help or quickies on this one would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Observe that:

$$
\int_0^4 \frac{y^2-4y+5}{2y^2-8y+11}\,\sin(y-2)\,\text{d}y = \int_{-2}^2 \frac{x^2+1}{2x^2+3}\,\sin(x)\,\text{d}x = 0
$$

since the integration interval is centered at $O$ with respect to which the integrand is symmetric.

Comment: WOW! wait could you explain a little more in detail. I do know a property that the integral of an odd function is 0 if the limits of the integral are centered to O. But still I didnt get how you brought in x in the picture

Comment: Aha Yes!!!. Beautiful Buddy

Comment: So was @ElizabethHuffman's main mistake forgetting to change the integration extremes?